# Warning seen java build path leading to HTTP status 404 error

Tags: eclipse

We have  warning about build path problem i.e. "Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment."
to our project which when running on tomcat 7 server gives a http status 404 error. Please guide us on how to solve this issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Go to windows (top, in the tabs) -> preferences and then type in JRE and click in INSTALLED JRE.
Add the JRE path or fix the already edited path.

Right click the project, click on properties, click on libraries, at the end  you will see the JRE. Select it as edit it as the WORKSPACE  default JRE.

Looks like your eclipse doesn't have the proper path to the JRE.
As far as the 404 is concerned that is a NOT FOUND ERROR. Once you are done with JRE fix, add the project to the tomcat and run the web server.